# Is the Laplace distribution a nascent delta function?

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-theory, convolution, dirac-delta

Define the normalized Laplace distribution as
$$
L(x;a) = \frac{1}{2a} \exp\Big(-\frac{|x|}{a}\Big) \quad (a>0).
$$
With the normalization out of the way, what we then need to prove is that for kind $f$
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} I_a[f] \equiv \lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty L(x;a) f(x) dx = f(0).
$$
I think I found a way with Fourier theory. Denoting the Fourier transform operator as $\text{FT}$, we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
Λ(ω;a) &=& \text{FT}[L] &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty L(x;a) \exp(i ω x) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{1+a^2 ω^2} \\
F(ω) &=& \text{FT}[f] &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \exp(i ω x) dx
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now $I_a[f]$ can be written as a convolution of $f(x)$ and $L(x;a)$ evaluated at zero:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 I_a[f] &=& \Big[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) L(y - x;a) dx\Big]_{y=0} \\
        &\equiv& (L * f)(0)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
With $\text{FT}^{-1}$ denoting the inverse Fourier transform operator, we then have
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
 I_a[f] &=& \text{FT}^{-1}[F(ω) \times Λ(ω;a)](0) \\
&=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \Big[\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(ω) \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{1+a^2 ω^2} \exp(-iωy) dω \Big]_{y=0} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(ω) \times \frac{1}{1+a^2 ω^2} dω.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ is easy to take:
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow0} I_a[f] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(ω) dω = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} f(0).
$$
This seems to imply that the proper nascent delta function is actually
$$
\sqrt{2\pi} \times L(x;a).
$$
**Question:** is this correct? But what about the normalization condition then? Thanks for any help!

Comment: It should be $\lim_{a \to 0} L(x; a) = \delta(x)$. I'll try to find what error you made to get that extra factor $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you have missed a factor when you write
$$ I_a[f] = \text{FT}^{-1}[F(ω) \times Λ(ω;a)](0)$$
See rule 109 and the "Fourier transform unitary, angular frequency" column in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional).
It should be
$$I_a[f] = (L*f)(0) = \sqrt{2\pi} \mathrm{FT}^{-1}[\Lambda \cdot F](0) = \cdots$$

---

Using the Fourier transform is unnecessary. It's easier to use a direct calculation:
$$
\langle L(\bullet;a), f \rangle 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2a} e^{-|x|/a} \, f(x) \, dx
= \{ x = ay \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} e^{-|y|} \, f(x/a) \, dx \\
\to \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} e^{-|y|} \, f(0) \, dx
= \left( \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|y|} \, dx \right) \, f(0)
= f(0) = \langle \delta, f \rangle.
$$
The limit is valid by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Comment: Haha, I could have known I was overdoing it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $p(x)$ is any pdf, $L(x;\,a):=\frac{1}{a}p\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ with $a>0$ is a nascent delta, viz. $$\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1}{a}p\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)g(x)dx=\lim_{a\to0^+}\int_{\Bbb R}p(y)g(ay)dy=g(0).$$In your case, $p(x):=\frac12\exp -x$. The mistake is in how you handle  the Fourier normalization. Your claim is equivalent to saying$$I_{a}\left[f\right] =\left.\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F\left(\omega\right)\Lambda\left(\omega,\,a\right)\exp\left(-i\omega y\right)d\omega\right|_{y=0}
 \\=\left.\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}f\left(x\right)\color{green}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}L\left(x^{\prime},\,a\right)\exp\left(i\omega\left(x+x^{\prime}-y\right)\right)dxdx^{\prime}d\omega\right|_{y=0},$$where the red factor is from the inverse FT, the blue one is from the FT defining $F$, and the green one is from the FT defining $\Lambda$. Integrating over $\omega$ first, the result is $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f\left(x\right)L\left(-x,\,a\right)dx,$$where the red factor survives after we use $$\int_{\Bbb R}\exp i\omega zd\omega=2\pi\delta(z).$$But the red factor was spurious to begin with. If you had instead defined $L(x,\,a)$ as $\delta(x)$, we'd have the same problem. Let's revisit the proof that a product of transforms is a transform of a convolution: the left-hand side is$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R}h(y)\exp(i\omega y)dy,$$while the right-hand side is$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R^2}g(x)h(y-x)\exp(i\omega y)dxdy=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Bbb R}g(x)\exp(i\omega x)dx\int_{\Bbb R}h(y)\exp(i\omega y)dy.$$So actually, the transformed convolution has an extra factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$, which is just what we need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since md2perpe was first and his answer is more or less equivalent to yours (but less comprehensive), I marked his as the accepted answer.

Comment: My normalization factor error reminds me of this quote from Numerical Recipes (2nd ed. p. 497): "We were raised on the ω-convention, but we changed! There are fewer factors of 2π to remember if you use the f-convention, especially when we get to discretely sampled data." I might have to change too. Thanks again!